# The name 'IOSNotificationDetails' isn't a class. Try correcting the name to match an existing class

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, flutter-notification

- *I'm actually following the Flutter Local Notification in YouTubel and the link is : [Flutter Local Notification](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2L8maZUY2hU&t=3459s)

I'm using windows laptop and android emulator and I also updated the build.gradle file.
I'm getting an error at

var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = new IOSNotificationDetails();

in displayNotification method. Can anyone help me with this?

here is the code snippet
[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQUrb.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class NotifyHelper {
   FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
     FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin(); //

initializeNotification() async {
//tz.initializeTimeZones();
final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsDarwin =
    DarwinInitializationSettings(
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification);

final AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
    const AndroidInitializationSettings("appicon");

final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
    InitializationSettings(
  iOS: initializationSettingsDarwin,
  android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
);
 await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
    onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: onDidReceiveNotificationResponse);
}

displayNotification({required String title, required String body}) async {
print("doing test");
var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'your channel id', 'your channel name',
    importance: Importance.max, priority: Priority.high);
var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = new IOSNotificationDetails();
// ignore: unnecessary_new
var platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(
    android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
  0,
  'You change your theme',
  'You changed your theme back !',
  platformChannelSpecifics,
  payload: 'It could be anything you pass',
);
}

void requestIOSPermissions() {
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
    .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
        IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
    ?.requestPermissions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
}

  void onDidReceiveNotificationResponse(
    NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {
    final String? payload = notificationResponse.payload;
   if (notificationResponse.payload != null) {
  debugPrint('notification payload: $payload');
} else {
  debugPrint("Notification Done");
}
Get.to(() => Container(
      color: Colors.white,
    ));
}

/*Future selectNotification(String? payload) async {
if (payload != null) {
  print('notification payload: $payload');
} else {
  print("Notification Done");
}
Get.to(() => Container(
      color: Colors.white,
    ));
}*/

 Future onDidReceiveLocalNotification(
  int id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) async {
// display a dialog with the notification details, tap ok to go to another page
/*showDialog(
  //context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
    title: Text(title),
    content: Text(body),
    actions: [
      CupertinoDialogAction(
        isDefaultAction: true,
        child: Text('Ok'),
        onPressed: () async {
          Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
          await Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => SecondScreen(payload),
            ),
          );
        },
      )
    ],
  ),
);*/
Get.dialog(const Text("Wellcome to flutter"));
}
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Check the [change log](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications/changelog) of the package. Version `10.0.0` introduced some breaking changes, and the guide you are following is probably earlier.

For example:

> [iOS][macOS] Breaking changes iOS and macOS classes have been renamed and refactored as they are based on the same operating system and share the same notification APIs. Rather than having a prefix of either IOS or MacOS, these are now replaced by classes with a Darwin prefix. For example, IOSInitializationSettings can be replaced with DarwinInitializationSettings

So for your current issue the solution might be using `DarwinNotificationDetails` instead of `IOSNotificationDetails`. But there can be other issues as well.